# LVM drive is not mounted after boot

Tags: lvm, ubuntu-12.04, mount

I have created an LVM with three physical disks named "orcafiler1". Problem is, every time after boot, the LVM drive is not mounted and I have to manually run

```
vgchange -ay orcafiler1
```

The fstab file contains

```
UUID=b57eae64-f270-4825-9ff0-040264fb33ac /               ext3    errors=remount-ro 0       0
# /home was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=c2d5decb-0615-48bd-9f8f-40eba852329e /home           ext3    defaults        0       0
# swap was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=54582723-d970-46f4-a24d-9c6d25ca16c6 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/orcafiler1/orcavolume       /data    ext3  defaults,nobootwait 0 0
```

How can I put it at boot time??

Te OS is Ubuntu 12.04

**UPDATE**

Additional info

```
$ dmesg|grep -iE "mapper|lvm"
[    3.711927] device-mapper: uevent: version 1.0.3
[    3.712064] device-mapper: ioctl: 4.22.0-ioctl (2011-10-19) initialised: dm-devel@redhat.com
```

And the output of `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf` is http://pastebin.mozilla.org/2873320

Comment: Why the `nobootwait` flag in the `fstab` entry? What if you remove it?

Comment: Because of this http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/showthread.php?p=4944133#post4944133

Comment: lvm volumes must be activated automatically anyway, without single entry in fstab.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add auto-activation according to this template to /etc/lvm/lvm.conf. This might help. I can't clearly say what's the reason, device is not available during check or startup lvm activation is not enable during bootup (ehm, ubuntu, dunno how it's done there, i am redhat guy).

```
# If auto_activation_volume_list is defined, each LV that is to be
# activated is checked against the list while using the autoactivation
# option (--activate ay/-a ay), and if it matches, it is activated.
#   "vgname" and "vgname/lvname" are matched exactly.
#   "@tag" matches any tag set in the LV or VG.
#   "@*" matches if any tag defined on the host is also set in the LV or VG
#
# auto_activation_volume_list = [ "vg1", "vg2/lvol1", "@tag1", "@*" ]
```

Comment: Is this syntax correct? `auto_activation_volume_list = [ "orcafiler1", "orcafiler1/orcavolume", "@*", "@*" ]`

Comment: Yeap, looks OK. Also, try to add lvmwait option to the kernel...

Comment: Do you mean `/etc/fstab`? Otherwise please explainthat to your reply

Comment: Here's manual for you https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters